# File browse for uploading a BLOB/CLOB and executing a SQL Script in Oracle APEX

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am after a means of using the "File/Browse" item within Oracle APEX v4.2.2 to load a sql script file into a Rich Text Area, make some changes within the sql file through the use of a PL/SQL page process, perform:

a) INSTR and REPLACE and then
b) execute this modified sql script in the Rich Text Editor within a PL/SQL page process using "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"

Is this actually possible and if so, how can I accomplish all of the above within Oracle APEX? That is from the file/browse point right through to the execute immediate step.

I basically need to access apex_application_files, take the blob_content and convert this into a clob (using dbms_lob.converttoclob), for processing.

Comment: Any reason why you'd need the dynamic sql? What is it you need to change to the sql? And the security implications?

Comment: All of this is possible. But what have you do before? Have you tried to do something? If you think that somebody will do all work for you - this is bad idea. First of all, try to solve this problem yourself, then, if you have questions or problems, ask here, post your code - we will help.

Comment: Appreciate where you are coming from NoGotnu. FYI, I tried using the dbms_lob.convertoclob package to no avail. Received a ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: invalid LOB locator specified: ORA-22275. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Before using c(b)lob variable you must allocate space. Read dbms_lob.createtemporary.